# What am I doing wrong in this procedure? (not allowed in this context)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FinishedPercent  (uinput varchar2) IS
  CURSOR obsah IS 
      SELECT * FROM DUNGEON
      NATURAL JOIN MY_CHARACTER;
  printObsah obsah%ROWTYPE;
  chartofind MY_CHARACTER.char_name%TYPE;
  dokoncene int;
  vsetky int;
BEGIN
  dokoncene := 0;
  vsetky := 0;
  SELECT DUNGEON.dungeon_ID INTO vsetky FROM DUNGEON;
  SELECT MY_CHARACTER.char_name 
  INTO chartofind 
  FROM MY_CHARACTER 
  INNER JOIN DUNGEON ON uinput = DUNGEON.dungeon_name 
  INNER JOIN CAVE ON CAVE.dungeon_sub = DUNGEON.dungeon_ID;
  open obsah;
  loop
    fetch obsah INTO printObsah;
    exit WHEN obsah%NOTFOUND;
    if (DUNGEON.status = 1) THEN
      dokoncene := dokoncene + 1;
    end if;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('Pre postavu ' || uinput || 'ostava ' || (vsetky - dokoncene) || 'questov, co je ' || (dokoncene * 100)/vsetky || 'percent');
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN 
      dbms_output.put_line('Pre postavu ' || uinput || 'ostava ' || (vsetky - dokoncene) || 'questov, co je 0 percent');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'An error encountered: ' || SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
  END;
  /
```

That is my procedure, basically its supposed to select a character and print out completed percentage of dungeons (out of all available to him).

I get the following error:

> Error(16,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   Error(16,17): PLS-00357:
>   Table,View Or Sequence reference 'DUNGEON.STATUS' not allowed in this
>   context

Basically in my table DUNGEON.status it is an integer of either 1 or 0 depending on it's completion. In my procedure i just want a simple loop that will increment 'dokoncene' parameter when the dungeon is completed. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Replace `DUNGEON.status` with `printObsah.status`?

Comment: @trincot technically fixes the error, but then when i try to exec the procedure I get the following one
`ORA-20001: An error encountered: -1422ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`

Comment: Presumably you have more than one dungeon in your table? Or more than one character in your dungeon?

Comment: @APC Well that's sort of the point. Basically what I want is for the procedure for user to input a character, the script will check all the dungeons that the character is assigned to (one character can be assigned to multiple dungeons) and print out the result. Any idea how could I get this result? - Also I might be missing something, but why would necessarily more dungeons/characters in a dungeon be conflicting?

Comment: This question is getting broader with every comment....

Comment: " why would necessarily more dungeons/characters in a dungeon be conflicting?" It's not conflicting. It's just that ORA-01422 is a basic error, one that is easily Google-able and so easy to fix for yourself.

Comment: SELECT ... INTO .. is expecting one and only one row, there will be an error  if it returns no rows or more than one row.  If you are expecting more than one, you'll need to work with a cursor as you've done elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Without any table definitions or sample data it is difficult to provide an answer but it seems that you are trying to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FinishedPercent (
  uinput varchar2
)
IS
  percentage NUMBER(3,2);
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG( CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) * 100
  INTO   percentage
  FROM   DUNGEON
  WHERE  name = uinput;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( percentage );
END;
/
```